# Is there still a "penalty box" on SO?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, banning, account-suspension

I read about the existence of a [penalty box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), but have never seen this in practice. Is this because the post is from 2009 and this particular quality-control has been stopped and replaced with the [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)? Or is it still in place?

I am asking because in contrast to the question ban, I could not find an official SO page stating this policy.

Comment: Disruptive users get banned all the time, it's not something they or the moderators tend to draw attention to.

Comment: Yes, we still put accounts in temporary suspension.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators: *Moderators can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.*

Comment: Somehow I read that earlier comment as *We put all accounts in temporary suspension* ...

Comment: Note that suspension is not very visible (users can't complain about it on meta, since, well, they're suspended). Be on the lookout for users with many badges but one rep, or check the profile of a user that behaved disruptively, and you might see some suspended users.

Comment: @rene that would be quite something... A mod being tired of users and just wanting a single day of quiet and suspending everyone... _Oh no! I haven't given anyone ideas, have I?_

Comment: There is a BIG difference between what the penalty box is intended to be, and the question ban.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I'll start at the top, and work my way down. Shouldn't be too hard to get at least the top 50 a nice timeout before Shog finds the 'demote' button..

Comment: Maybe start with that Shog guy ....

Comment: @MartijnPieters can't you ban Shog before he bans you?

Comment: @Patrice: I suspect he may have a back door back in..

Comment: I think the only correct answer is "Yes, would you like a tour?" :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the reference to the particular link. I was indeed looking for some official reference. Does SO publish any info on how often such bans/suspensions occur? I'm just trying to get a general sense of how rare this is.

Comment: @splinter no, no numbers are published. Suspensions are mostly a non-public event between moderators and user. It happens a once or twice a week here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: IMO no, there is no penalty box. No matter if you're Satan incarnate and the most hated user on the planet who has every suspension applied to them that the site supports - you can still search. And that happens to be the primary function of this repository of ours.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, temporary suspensions, a.k.a "the penalty box", still exist and are in use.

Mods don't make big deals out of when they use them, to give the suspended user some privacy in the matter. (I would hazard a guess this is also to keep each suspension from becoming a huge drama.)

However, they are indeed still in use, and likely will be for the foreseeable future. After all, users aren't going to all magically get along and follow all the rules.